# CIM_Battery WMI Class has no instances

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, wmi

I am trying to create a C# Application that records the battery percentage over time, and to do that I have been trying to use the .NET WMI API. I looked on MSDN and found that there is a WMI class called [`CIM_Battery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387189(v=vs.85).aspx#properties), and confirmed its existence with [`wbemtest.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180684.aspx).

Upon closer inspection in `wbemtest.exe`, it appears that the `CIM_Battery` class doesn't have any instances that I can read from.

[image: Screenshot of CIM_Battery Class]

Is this normal, or is my system just broken?

Comment: So your computer has a battery?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Yes, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that isn't working, but another way to do it:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C powercfg /batteryreport";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

This will output the battery life to a file: `C:/Windows/System32/battery-report.html`

You can then scrape that page. It's a bit overkill, but there might be more data in there that you can use for your diagnostics.

Edit: also a `powershell` class in .net (System.Management.Automation) assembly. So you could make a .ps1 with the line: 
`(Get-WmiObject win32_battery).estimatedChargeRemaining`

```
PowerShell psinstance = PowerShell.Create();
psinstance.AddScript(scriptPath);
var results = psinstance.Invoke();
```

Edit2: The CIM (common information model) classes are parent classes upon which the WMI classes are built. `win32_xxx` classes monitor and manage system hardware and features and are located in in CIM. Instead of pulling from `CIM_Battery` parent class, pull from the `win32_battery` class instead.

Comment: Is this really the only way to do it? It just seems... unclean.

Comment: there's also the powershell command `(Get-WmiObject win32_battery).estimatedChargeRemaining` and returns the Percentage left. Might be easier? There is a powershell class in .net so you can grab the output pretty easy prob

Comment: Wouldn't the PowerShell call to WMI return nothing because there are no instances?

Comment: Open a powershell window and paste the command and see if you get a result

Comment: Yes, the PS Command does work. OH, I think I figured it out: are the `CIM_[WHATEVER]` things just the classes and the other ones are the instances? Let me try the `win32_battery` class.

Comment: THANK YOU! I will accept your answer if you include what I said in my previous comment: the `CIM_Battery` class is just a template for the `win32_battery` class which implements `CIM_Battery`. That is why `CIM_Battery` has no instances, `win32_battery` does.

Comment: @ifconfig added more info in the 2nd edit. Glad you figured it out!